# Find the limit (lhopitals?)

Tags: calculus

Find the limit: 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^{\sin x}\ln(1+t)\,dt
$$

Not sure how I should start this? Is it straight forward evaluation or should I use lhopitals rule?

Comment: I have added some MathJax to your post to improve readability.  Please verify that I have correctly interpreted your intent.

Answer (score 4):

You have a $0/0$ form here. Use L'hospital once and then the fact that
$\ln(1 + x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$ to get
$$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over 2x}\cdot\ln(1 + \sin(x))\cdot \cos(x)
= \lim_{x\to 0}{\ln(1 + \sin(x))\over 2x}
= \lim_{x\to 0}{\sin(x)\over 2x } = {1\over 2}.$$